# Use CLR function for convert Hierarchyid to string in visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, sql-server, clr, sqlclr, hierarchyid

Please advise me.
I try to write a **CLR** function for SQL server. 
I using the Microsoft document for write below function [Ref-LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/hierarchical-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)
Finding Ancestors by Using the CLR
A common operation involving two nodes in a hierarchy is to find the lowest common ancestor. This can be written in either Transact-SQL or CLR, because the **hierarchyid** type is available in both. CLR is recommended because performance will be faster.

Use the following CLR code to list ancestors and to find the lowest common ancestor:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Types;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;

public partial class HierarchyId_Operations
{
    [SqlFunction(FillRowMethodName = "FillRow_ListAncestors")]
    public static IEnumerable ListAncestors(SqlHierarchyId h)
    {
        while (!h.IsNull)
        {
            yield return (h);
            h = h.GetAncestor(1);
        }
    }
    public static void FillRow_ListAncestors(
        Object obj,
        out SqlHierarchyId ancestor
        )
    {
        ancestor = (SqlHierarchyId)obj;
    }

    public static HierarchyId CommonAncestor(
        SqlHierarchyId h1,
        HierarchyId h2
        )
    {
        while (!h1.IsDescendantOf(h2))
            h1 = h1.GetAncestor(1);

        return h1;
    }
}
```

But i see this error :
[image]

I try to use Visual Studio solution's, but not work truly .
then use internet search and find Nugget , but my nugget is disable.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name `HierarchyId` in the .NET code appears to be a type-o in the documentation. There is only `SqlHierarchyId` within SQLCLR. In fact, this was even mentioned in one of the 3 closed issues associated with that documentation page (at the bottom of that page, click on the "Closed" tab):

[CommonAncestor correctness](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/2386#issuecomment-514086136)

Opened by "FYfrog" on 2019-06-27.